# Squeezing `rem`-sized items toward center of a full-width flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

Quite a bit of code involved in this question. The code [can be found here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEbrJj?editors=1100) if you'd like to play around with it. In order to demonstrate layout I needed to insert some ipsum-like text.

## HTML

```
<main>
  <section data-pc-layout="mast">
    <article>
      <header><h2>Seriously serious seriousness</h2></header>
      <p>Intrinsicly pursue emerging alignments before quality benefits. Holisticly disseminate quality convergence rather than resource maximizing architectures. Distinctively expedite client-centered paradigms and business networks. Monotonectally productize bleeding-edge expertise with extensive results. Interactively brand next-generation total linkage and multidisciplinary expertise.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <!-- /TEXT RIGHT IMAGE -->

  <!-- TEXT LEFT IMAGE -->
  <section data-pc-layout="mast" data-pc-scheme="dark">
    <article>
      <header><h2>No really, so serial</h2></header>
      <p>Efficiently network intuitive applications rather than exceptional communities. Synergistically scale cross-platform experiences after alternative leadership. Credibly innovate cross-media users rather than cross functional "outside the box" thinking. Efficiently restore world-class results and efficient architectures. Energistically provide access to B2C e-markets with standardized results.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <!-- /TEXT LEFT IMAGE -->

  <!-- TEXT 1/2 -->
  <section data-pc-layout="half">
    <article>
      <header><h3>Boom</h3></header>
      <p>Authoritatively generate maintainable innovation before virtual bandwidth. Compellingly innovate vertical opportunities without high-quality content. Dynamically foster proactive convergence for goal-oriented resources. Enthusiastically mesh progressive products through value-added process improvements. Dramatically pontificate just in time synergy and economically sound bandwidth.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <!-- /TEXT 1/2 -->

  <!-- TEXT 1/2 -->
  <section data-pc-layout="half">
    <article>
      <header><h3>Shackalacka</h3></header>
          <p>Credibly plagiarize 24/365 testing procedures for synergistic ROI. Globally integrate innovative relationships with focused niches. Synergistically seize cost effective communities whereas multidisciplinary infomediaries. Credibly simplify business users whereas performance based sources. Dynamically leverage other's virtual strategic theme areas vis-a-vis process-centric vortals.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <!-- /TEXT 1/2 IMAGE -->

  <!-- TEXT FULL -->
  <section data-pc-layout="mast">
    <article>
      <header><h3>Getcha headlines here! Hot headlines!</h3></header>
      <p>Rapidiously repurpose distinctive products rather than standardized action items. Intrinsicly drive equity invested opportunities without ubiquitous products. Interactively underwhelm best-of-breed channels whereas proactive ROI. Competently negotiate effective infrastructures whereas functionalized sources. Quickly communicate out-of-the-box imperatives after strategic metrics.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <!-- /TEXT FULL -->
</main>
```

On generating HTML for dynamic content, some sections can be half-width but should have a `max-width` of a given `rem` value. Given that other sections may be full-width and have a dark background spanning the entire viewport width, I cannot constrain sections inside a container.

Furthermore, since the number of sections and their order is dynamic, I cannot wrap two half-width sections in a container element for a "row" of two half-width elements.

## CSS

```
body {
  font-size: 10px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 16px;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #ffaaff;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

section[data-pc-scheme="dark"] {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
}

section article {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 75rem;
  margin: auto;
}

section[data-pc-layout="half"] {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  margin: auto;
}
```

The half-width sections are sized properly, but my goal—and where I'm running into issues—is that I would like to "squeeze" the two half-width sections toward the center without using any other containers (removing the white spacing in the middle of the sections as seen in the below screenshot). The two sections should form columns whose edges align with the edges of the content above and below.

[image: Alignment Fixes]

This is something that I would *expect* `justify-content: center` to handle when placed on the `main` element (as it is in the CSS), but this is not so.

I'm assuming I'm missing something simple because this is probably a common scenario, but—as usually happens—I've been staring at this for long enough to make my eyes slightly crossed and cannot think of the proper solution.

Comment: Considering those elements have a padding of 3rem, no wonder they won't meed in the middle. Also, we don't want to parse full code, so make a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue, and do note, the essential code part should be within the question, not linked to a 3rd party

Comment: Also, minor issues like this is very easy to find using the browsers dev.tools., where one quick can see the applied styles and how an element is rendered on the page

Comment: @LGSon I have indeed played with dev-tools for quite a while with no good results. A more minimal example on the way

Comment: @LGSon thank you for keeping me in check ;) I've edited the question and the code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I found what makes the problem.

You should edit `margin`.

I got it

Try to edit like that.

```
section[data-pc-layout="half"] {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  //margin: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what margin you speak of, but since it looks like you're using dev-tools here to highlight the element, these margins are, I believe, handled by flex and are not explicitly placed on the elements anywhere in my code.

Comment: That's the simplest thing in the world. Thank you so much. That was old code that was left in to center the elements before I was using flex. You rock!